# I want to create a "CGI script" in python that stays resident in memory and services multiple requests

Tags: python, frameworks, cgi, pylons

I have a website that right now, runs by creating static html pages from a cron job that runs nightly.

I'd like to add some search and filtering features using a CGI type script, but my script will have enough of a startup time (maybe a few seconds?) that I'd like it to stay resident and serve multiple requests.

This is a side-project I'm doing for fun, and it's not going to be super complex. I don't mind using something like Pylons, but I don't feel like I need or want an ORM layer.

What would be a reasonable approach here?

EDIT: I wanted to point out that for the load I'm expecting and processing I need to do on a request, I'm confident that a single python script in a single process could handle all requests without any slowdowns, especially since my dataset would be memory-resident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org/wsgi/WsgiStart) is for ;)

I don't know off hand what the simplest way to turn a CGI script into a WSGI application is, though (I've always had that managed by a framework). It shouldn't be too tricky, though.

That said, [An Introduction to the Python Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI)](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/wsgi-intro/what-is-wsgi.html) seems to be a reasonable introduction, and you'll also want to take a look at [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (assuming you're using Apache…)

Comment: The thing that struck me about WSGI, as I was reading about it, was that it wasn't really intended to be used by "end-users" like this; it was more like an interface between other frameworks and the web server. 

Anyone here tried using WSGI directly? Is it usable?

Comment: writing in wsgi I would consider easier than writing a straight cgi. If you use Webob it's even easier.

Comment: Ok, WSGI looks like the way to go here. Thanks!

This link (one of the links above) sealed it for me:
http://bitworking.org/news/Why_so_many_Python_web_frameworks

Comment: Or, use werkzeug.  Or use almost any web framework.  They're all easier than messing with CGI.

Comment: @S.Lott: Can't say I agree with that. There's a certain simplicity in being able to just print out some HTTP headers and HTML, compared to setting up models, views, controllers, templates, databases, and so on.

Comment: I agree with @S.Lott – learning a simple framework is well worth the time invested, even if you won't use it very often. When I picked it up a couple years ago, web.py (http://webpy.org/) was very simple, and I've heard good things about Werkzeug too.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should direct your search towards inter process commmunication and make a search process that returns the results to the web server. This search process will be running all the time assuming you have your own server.

Comment: No, I'd say this is the wrong way to do it. IPC is tricky and that's almost what WSGI already does: when `mod_wsgi` starts, it `fork()`s and starts a process to run your script, then when Apache gets a request for a URL which serves your script, that request gets handed to `mod_wsgi` which then hands it to your script. All pretty much transparent to you.

Comment: @david you are of course right. I don't know how WSGI works, but op didn't like it so I was trying to find an anternative solution.